# Accessing parameters in silverlight without access to Application_Startup

Tags: silverlight, parameters, startup

I am currently trying to send parameters to a silverlight webapplication via url parameters.

This is relative simple when you write the whole application yourselves and have access to the StartupEvent.

In this particular case I just write a plugin to an exisiting silverlight application and does not have access to the `Application_Startup` and `StartupEvent`.

Is it possible to capture the URLparameters in the ASPX file and make them accessible to an object/class (my plugin) inside the application?

Thanks,
-Helge

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is to access your url to get your parameters, you do not need to have access to Application_Startup. You can obtain your current url using this code:

```
//get input url
_inputUrl = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Query;
```

Then you could parse your input url to get your parameters.

Hope it helps.